# ¿Se puede añadir un salto de línea a la cabecera en la definición de una función?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una definición de una función a la que es necesario pasarle muchos parámetros y la cabecera es lo suficientemente larga como para que tenga que estar desplazando la barra horizontal para ver toda la cabecera.

Ejemplo:

```
def lines(title = "Title",xlab = "Abscissa",ylab = "Ordinate",show = True,leg = None,a,b,datos_x,datos_y,datos_z,longitud_x,longitud_y,longitud_z,*x,*L):
```

¿Existe alguna forma de añadir un salto de línea a la cabecera para que se muestre en varias líneas como en el siguiente ejemplo?

```
 def lines(title = "Title",xlab = "Abscissa",ylab = "Ordinate",show = True,leg = None,
a,b,datos_x,datos_y,datos_z,longitud_x,longitud_y,longitud_z,*x,*L):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hay problema

Es más es una buena norma de estilo el que no ocupe mas de 72-79 caracteres de ancho el codigo...

**Tamaño máximo de línea: limita todas las líneas a un máximo de 79 caracteres.**

Todavía existen muchos dispositivos por ahí que están limitados a 80 caracteres por línea; además limitando el ancho de las ventanas a 80 caracteres posibilitas el tener varias ventanas una al lado de otra.

El ajuste de línea por defecto en este tipo de dispositivos no da buenos resultados.

Por lo tanto, por favor limita todas las líneas a un máximo de 79 caracteres. 
Para cadenas de texto largas (cadenas de documentación o comentarios), es aconsejable limitar el ancho a 72 caracteres.

*La forma preferida de dividir líneas largas es utilizar la característica de Python de continuar las líneas de forma implícita dentro de paréntesis, corchetes y llaves*.

Si es necesario, puedes añadir un par de paréntesis extra alrededor de una expresión, pero algunas veces queda mejor usar una barra invertida.

**Asegurate de indentar la línea** siguiente de forma correcta.

Ejemplos:

```
class Rectangle(Blob):

def __init__(self, width, height,
             color='black', emphasis=None, highlight=0):
    if width == 0 and height == 0 and \
       color == 'red' and emphasis == 'strong' or \
       highlight > 100:
        raise ValueError("sorry, you lose")
    if width == 0 and height == 0 and (color == 'red' or
                                       emphasis is None):
        raise ValueError("I don't think so")
    Blob.__init__(self, width, height,
                  color, emphasis, highlight)
```

Comment: Entendido. ¿Y si quiero hacer lo mismo para un texto largo que quiero mostrar por pantalla? Por ejemplo ´print ("blablablablablablablabla lololololololololo")´ en dos líneas.

Comment: Revisa por favor [answer], **evita realizar varias respuestas**.

Comment: @Jorgesys Disculpa, soy nuevo y no acabo de interiorizar el funcionamiento de SO. Ahora qué hago ¿borro mi comentario con la pregunta sobre el texto largo?

Comment: @Zhisi Hola, la persona que responde puede actualizar su respuesta con nueva información, no realizar multiples respuestas.

Answer (score -1):

El Carácter de escape para un salto de línea es **\n** que sería lo que tendrías que concatenar a tu cadena para tener el salto.

En una línea:

```
print ("blablablablablablablabla lololololololololo")
```

En dos líneas:

```
print ("blablablablablablablabla" + '\n' + "lololololololololo")
```

ó

```
print ("blablablablablablablabla\nlololololololololo")
```

http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/2/introduction.html#cadenas-de-caracteres

Comment: Revisa por favor [answer], **evita realizar varias respuestas**.

Comment: Como te comenta Jorgesys deberías editar tu respuesta original si quieres responder a la duda que el OP plantea en el comentario en vez de crear una nueva. Ten en cuenta que esta respuesta no responde a la pregunta original y que los comentarios son volátiles, alguien puede interpretar que no responde a la pregunta, votar negativo o reportarla para su cierre. Por otro lado, creo que el comentario del OP va más en realidad por como usar varias lineas a la hora de definir un string muy largo para no rebasar la "norma" de los 79 caracteres: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10660435/7131499. Saludos.

Comment: Se han realizado dos preguntas distintas. Por eso mi motivo de 2 respuestas distintas.