# como dividir una linea de código python en api blender

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

he estado buscando como dividir lineas de código largas que sobrepasan los 80 caracteres por línea en lineas mas cortas donde no se rompa el código, estoy aprendiendo python y honestamente no soy muy afecto a este lenguaje mis necesidades me hacen aprenderlo pero quiero aprender bien de forma correcta

[¿Se puede añadir un salto de línea a la cabecera en la definición de una función?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124415/se-puede-a%c3%b1adir-un-salto-de-l%c3%adnea-a-la-cabecera-en-la-definici%c3%b3n-de-una-funci%c3%b3n)

si entiendo un poco lo que dice esta respuesta pero no se como aplicarlo a mi linea de codigo

que seria la siguiente:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aún cumpliendo las [recomendaciones de estilo definidas en PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation), podemos tener varias posibilidades. Una práctica común y que deja tu código bastante legible es colocar cada argumento identado cuatro espacios debajo de la linea de llamada. La tupla pasada a `layers`, que es muy larga, puedes igualmente dividirla  en las lineas que necesites:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(
    radius=1,
    view_align=False,
    enter_editmode=False,
    location=(0, 0, 0),
    layers=(
        True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False
        )
)
```

Si no he contado mal, la linea más larga es de 77 caracteres. Obviamente, si llamas al método desde un nivel extra de identación (desde dentro e otra función por ejemplo) deberás dividir la tupla en más lineas para no superar los 79 caracteres.

El paréntesis de cierre, puedes colocarlo bien al nivel del primer carácter que no sea un espacio en blanco de la linea anterior o al mismo nivel que la linea que causa la construcción multilínea (la llamada la `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add` en este caso).

Algunas veces puede ser útil definir a tupla fuera de la llamada y pasar la variable:

```
layers = (
    True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
    False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False
    )

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(
    radius=1,
    view_align=False,
    enter_editmode=False,
    location=(0, 0, 0),
    layers=layers
    )
```

Recuerda que PEP-8 no es más que convenciones, que aunque es recomendable seguirlas para estandarizar el código y facilitar su lectura por otros programadores, no son normas estrictas que tengas que seguir si o si. Python como lenguaje obliga a muy pocas cosas al programador.

Comment: muchas gracias, por fin alguien me supo explicar con toda su paciencia y no me hizo odiar python, maestro, soy tu fan jejej no dudes que acudiré a ti con mas preguntas, estoy aprendiendo python por mi cuenta en mi tiempo libre y me esta costando algo mas que canas verdes

Comment: la comunidad blender es vive una falacia de autocracia que yo llamo la Rosendal Ton-ada, y son muy dados a ser heaters y criticar mucho por no darles con cucharaditas de bebe las lineas de codigo, y lo puedo probar con las respuestas estupidas que he recibido de los supuestos expertos de las comunidades blender, así que para poder avanzar en mi conocimiento decidí darles por su lado y darles con cucharita de bebe sus lineas de codigo

Comment: no estaba tan lejos de la solución, donde me fallo fue que comencé a indentar la linea después de la primera coma dentro del paréntesis, bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1,  - y después de esto quebré la linea y me mandaba un error, pero ahora me quedo muy claro, muchas gracias nuevamente